# Emgu.CV Mat vs Image<,> pixel access Get Set

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, mat

I'm trying to figure out the best practice for using emgu.CV 4.8.1 in C# .NETFramework 4.8, I see in [this](https://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images) tutorial  that the newer versions of openCV is based on mat and from some test that I have run I see that Mat performance seems better, in my application I need to access single pixel very often (i.e. rebinning, interpolation, convolution, remapping) with images that operation is simple using Image<,>.Data[,,] but with mat I dont know how to do that without reallocating the memory.

Should I use Images and forget about mat or does a pixel access method exists?

thanks.

Comment: Just in general, you should try to use whatever type that best describes your data. If you are handling Images, you should probably use the `Image` class. There can be reasons to use a more abstract data structure, but if image works for your use case, use it. I would not put *to much* faith into third party tutorials of unknown age, source and quality.

Comment: As for performance. In general, the more effort you put in optimizing, the faster it will get, but there are diminishing returns. If performance was the *only* concern you would likely be writing CUDA code, not c#. So the general recommendation is to write readable code first, and only optimize when, and where, it is needed.

Comment: please don't link to any material discussing outdated versions of opencv. 2.4 is outdated. -- that emgu wiki article is outdated as well. -- how about you give opencvsharp a look?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I deleted the link to opencv 2.4